# Red Hat - internal port forwarding blocked

Tags: firewall, redhat, http, port, node.js

I'm working on Red Hat, and I'm trying to set up a web service. I've implemented a port-forwarding from 80 to 8080 to access tomcat8 service.

```
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080
```

The server receives an HTTP request from the outside (which works well thanks to the port forwarding), depending on the request it will send a request to nodejs and nodejs will answer. The problem is that when nodejs try to answer to the request from tomcat8, the connection is refused:

```
problem with request: connect ECONNREFUSED <my_ip_adress>:80
```

I've tried to accept every TCP connection on port 80, but it doesn't do anything.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p UDP --port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I've also tried to modify the firewall in accepting every TCP connection on port 80 on the `public` and the `internal` zones.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=80/tcp
```

And to add specifical port forwarding from 80 to 8080 in the internal zone of the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080
```

Also when I try to connect to localhost on port 80, the connection is refused.

```
telnet localhost 80
```

I have come to the conclusion that the port forwarding is not done internally.
Does anybody know how to authorize this kind of internal communication?

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe it can help, when I execute `telnet hostname 80` on another machine in the network, it can connect. When I execute `telnet hostname 8080` on the concerned machine, it also connects correctly (as expected by the port forwarding and the routing table). However, when I execute `telnet hostname 80`, the connection is refused.

I think that the question is different from the "duplicated" one because the problem here is that there is no internal port forwarding for whatever reason.

** UPDATE 2**
The output of `iptables -t nat -nvL` (I've truncated the empty chains):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   424 PREROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7   424 PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7   424 PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   185 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   185 POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   185 POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   185 POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   133 POST_public  all  --  *      ens192  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    1    52 POST_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain POST_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   185 POST_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   185 POST_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   185 POST_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   424 PRE_public  all  --  ens192 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 PRE_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]        

Chain PRE_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   424 PRE_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7   424 PRE_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7   424 PRE_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PRE_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   424 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x64 to::8080
```

The output of `iptables -nvL` (I've truncated the empty chains):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  630  150K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3   156 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  1069 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  1069 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  1069 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    8   416 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    1   229 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 570 packets, 132K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  635  141K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  ens192 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      ens192  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  1069 IN_public  all  --  ens192 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  1069 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  1069 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  1069 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    7   424 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW mark match 0x64
```

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? Is it possible for you and just for the the test to disable the firewall?

Comment: Concerning selinux, executing `getenforce` I got `Enforcing`. Yes for test purpose I can disable the firewall.

Comment: Is it possible just for test matters to disable selinux?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: In order to temporarily disable selinux, run: `setenforce 0`

Comment: It's done. I've also found how to disable the firewall: `systemctl disable firewalld`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90547/discussion-between-bastian-nanchen-and-itai-ganot).

Comment: How did you set up the port forwarding?

Comment: `firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080`, which works well for communication with the outside.

Comment: The port forwarding only applies to connections from outside, not to localhost connections. Those connections to backend services should just continue to use 8080. Or you should put the service on port 80.

Comment: where the nodejs service is located? is it on the same machine?

Comment: @MichaelHampton there is not a way to do port-forwarding locally?

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar the nodejs service is located on the same service.

Comment: You can, but firewalld can't. You would have to create a direct rule. But again, you probably should have the service on port 80 to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't have a say in the matter about having tomcat8 on port 80. I need to make it work this way. Do you see a method to make it work?

Comment: That just raises the question: where is your web server? It's normal to have a web server (e.g. nginx) on port 80 which proxies to tomcat and nodejs.

Comment: Tomcat8 is the web server. It's more a matter of legacy the fact that we use port 8080 for tomcat8.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic through a Linux box can be controlled in one of 3 hooks:

- INPUT
- FORWARD
- OUTPUT

And if some kind of translation is done like port forwarding additional hooks are used:

- POSTROUTING
- PREROUTING

port forwarding is taking place in the PREROUTING hook (in the nat table), as the name suggests it occurs before routing.
So traffic coming from outside to the local process passes through PREROUTING, get port-forwarded (the destination port is changed from 80 to 8080) and then the INPUT chain.

The local Tomcat then connects to the local nodejs through the loopback interface and because there is no rule of port forwarding on the loopback interface nodejs is receiving traffic from Tomcat sourced with 8080 port and not 80.

Bottom line, local processes uses loopback interface to communicate with each other and unless you add a port forwarding on this interface connecting to localhost:80 is connecting to no where because there is no process listening on localhost:80

Comment: I applied these two new rules: `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.31:8080` and `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.10.31 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` but there is no difference. Were you thinking about something else?

Comment: @BastianNanchen Try ``iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lo  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080``

Comment: Still nothing. Yet I have noticed in doing a `tcpdump` that the source ip address is 192.168.10.31 and the destination as well.

Comment: can you print the result of ``iptables -nvL`` and ``iptables -t nat -nvL``

Comment: I've updated the question with the results of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL`.

Comment: @BastianNanchen in the ``filter`` rules ``INPUT`` chain modify the first rule to accept not only ``RELATED`` and ``ESTABLISHED`` states but also the ``NEW`` state. Dropping syn packets prohibits connection establishment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90616/discussion-between-bastian-nanchen-and-soulimane-mammar).

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this as a comment but my profile is too new.

It's entirely possible this is a sysctl kernel issue rather than iptables.

try running:

```
 /sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

to check if it is set to 1.

If it's set to zero you'll need to enable it running:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and make sure you set it in `/etc/sysctl.conf` as well so it survives a reboot.

Comment: Yes, the value `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to 0.

Comment: you'll need to change it to 1 then `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: if that's not set the kernel won't do ip forwarding

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I wanted to say that it's set to 1. Sorry...long day